# PhantomJS not rendering images stored locally

Tags: rendering, phantomjs

I have not been able to render some images stored in my server properly using phantomjs. If I use any other image stored on the internet in works fine. So I was wondering if someone out there can tell me some server configuration I should've set up.

I have this phantomjs script:

```
page.open(html, function () {

window.setTimeout(function( status ) {
    page.clipRect = { left: 0, top: 0, width: 640, height: 800 };
    page.render(outputFolder + htmlBaseName + '.png');
    console.log('rendered');
    phantom.exit();
}, 2000);

});
```

And a html file containing a table and these images:

```
<img src="http://myServerURL/image1.png" style="width: 198px; min-height: 181px; max-height: 181px; height: 181px; max-width: 198px;" width="198" height="181">
<img src="http://myServerURL/image2.png" style="width: 198px; min-height: 181px; max-height: 181px; height: 181px; max-width: 198px;" width="198" height="181">
<img src="http://phantomjs.org/img/phantomjs-logo.png" style="width: 198px; min-height: 181px; max-height: 181px; height: 181px; max-width: 198px;" width="198" height="181">
```

And I'm getting this in return: [image]

My images can be viewed from the internet

Comment: Please register to the [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) and [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render local Images in PDF, you have to convert that image to base-64 and pass this value in src attribute of img tag.